# make:auth não criar Route::group

Tags: php, laravel

Estou estudando laravel acompanhando o seguinte [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf7sUra91XE&list=PLInBAd9OZCzylabwvLeJIa9gxbS7MmzNY&index=7) e travei na parte em que o instrutor dá a seguinte linha de comando

```
 php artisan make:auth
```

No dele cria o seguinte bloco:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function (){

    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

No meu só cria as linhas:

```
 Route::auth();

 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Esse se eu colocar manualmente o bloco não funciona.

Dá um

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
FatalErrorException
```

Tem problema se não tiver esse grupo?

Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Possivelmente seu .env esta com o debug desativado assim is erros ficam mascarados. O erro que voce devs estar obtendo, poasivelmente as refere a nao existir o grupo web no arquivo de middleware. Mais para confirmar isso, primeiro habilita o debug do .env para ver a real pilha de erros.

Comment: Provavelmente você e quem fez o vídeo estão usando versões diferentes do Laravel. Acho que o erro que você está tendo é por causa do middleware. Em todo caso, é como Mauricio disse no comentário acima. Ativa o debug ou consulta o log de erros, pois vai te ajudar a entender o que deu de errado.

Comment: Realmente, o vídeo foi feito em maio de 2016. E eu estou tendo dificuldade em acompanhar o vídeo. No dele dá certo e no meu não. Tentei continuar, mas não deu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem problemas se `Route::auth();` não estiver em um grupo de rotas.